# Drawing on a canvas declared in another function

Tags: java, swing, object, paintcomponent

I have an application which has a swing user interface class, which has buttons that send variables to a canvas class like so;

```
public class createWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    createCanvas canvas = new createCanvas(10, 10);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    public createWindow()
    {
        mainPanel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

createCanvas is a class which declares a paintComponent;

```
public class createCanvas extends JPanel
{
    int xValue;
    int yValue;
    int xCoordinate;
    int yCoordinate;

    public createCanvas(int x, int y)
    {
        xValue = x;
        yValue = y;
    }

    public void setXCoordinate(int x)
    {
        xCoordinate = x;
    }

    public void setYCoordinate(int y)
    {
        yCoordinate = y;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawGrid(g, this.xValue, this.yValue);
        g.fillArc(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 6, 6, 0, 360);
    }

    public drawGrid(Graphics g, int xLength, int yLength)
    {
        //creates a grid that is xLength x yLength
    }
}
```

However, I also have a selection of Objects which I want to have a .draw() function, which can use the paintComponent in createCanvas.
The problem is, of course, when I need to draw the node on the grid, I can set the coordinates, but how do I display the node on the canvas I declared in createWindow?

```
public class Node()
{
    int xCoordinate;
    int yCoordinate;

    //Suitable constructors, sets, gets
    public void draw()
    {
        createCanvas canvas = new createCanvas();
        canvas.setXCoordinate(this.xCoordinate);
        canvas.setYCoordinate(this.yCoordinate);
        canvas.repaint();
    }
}
```

So, I am wondering if there is a way for me to keep what I have drawn on the canvas in createWindow, as well as what I draw in my Object class.

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: Use Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters

Comment: Thank you for the tip, any help on the issue or is the question not clear?

Comment: You question is unclear. What is `createCanvas` and what exactyl are you trying to accomplish. What objects are you talking about?

Comment: In my effort to make the question simple, I fear I have gone too vague, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is have  the `draw` method in your object take a `Graphics` argument. This `Graphics` object will be the same `Graphics` context in your `paintComponent` method. You can create the object in your `JPanel` class. Something like this

```
public class Circle {
    int x, y;

    public Circle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void drawCirlce(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Then in you `JPanel` class

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100);

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        circle.drawCircle(g);
    }
}
```

You can have a `setter` for the `x` and `y` in your `Circle` class. You should change them somewhere in your `JPanel` class then call `repaint()` afterwards. You could move it with the press of a key or you can animate it with a `java.util.Timer`. For example

With a [**Timer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100);

    public CirclePanel() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
                circle.x += 10;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       circle.drawCircle(g);
    }
}
```

With a [**key binding**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100);

    public CirclePanel() {
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED_IN_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "moveRight");
        getActionMap().put("moveRight", new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                circle.x += 10;
                repaint();
            } 
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       circle.drawCircle(g);
    }
}
```

With a [**button press**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100);

    public CirclePanel() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Move Right");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                circle.x += 10;
                repaint();
            } 
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       circle.drawCircle(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about with a button press?

Comment: That will work fine also. Just change the coordinates and `repaint` inside the `actionPerformed` of the button's listener

Comment: I've added the example for the button press.

Comment: Alas with one problem fixed another has arisen, but your help has been invaluable.

Much obliged.